# appending 4 bytes to byte array

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to translate this code into python from c,

```
} else if(remaining == 3) {
    firstB = (BYTE*)&buf[0];
    *firstB ^= 0x12;
    firstW = (WORD*)&buf[1];
    *firstW ^= 0x1234;
    i = 3;
}

for(; i<len;)
{
    then = (DWORD*)&buf[i];
    *then ^= 0x12345678;
    i += 4;
}
```

What I got:

```
elif remaining == 3:
    new_packet.append(struct.unpack('<B', packet_data[0:1])[0] ^ 0x12)
    new_packet.append(struct.unpack('<H', packet_data[1:3])[0] ^ 0x1234)
    i = 3

while i < packet_len:
    new_packet.append(struct.unpack('<L', packet_data[i:i+4])[0] ^ 0x12345678)
    i += 4

return new_packet
```

problem is I always get `ValueError: byte must be in range(0, 256)`.

So I must be translating this wrong. So what am I missing or is there any way I can make this more efficient? Why is the python code wrong?

---

update

```
new_bytes = struct.unpack('<H', packet_data[1:3])
new_packet.append(new_bytes[0] ^ 0x1234)
```

I'm getting the first few bytes right with above, but nothing ever right with code below:

```
new_bytes = struct.unpack('<BB', packet_data[1:3])
new_packet.append(new_bytes[0] ^ 0x12)
new_packet.append(new_bytes[1] ^ 0x34)
```

So my problem still remains inside the while loop, and the question remains how to do this right:

```
new_bytes = struct.unpack('<L', packet_data[i:i+4])
new_packet.append(new_bytes[0] ^ 0x12345678)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
new_packet.append(struct.unpack('<H', packet_data[1:3])[0] ^ 0x1234)
```

tries to append a two-byte value to the byte array. One fix is to append the two bytes of the word separately:

```
# Little-endian, so the first byte is low byte of the word.
new_bytes = struct.unpack('BB', packet_data[1:3])
new_packet.append(new_bytes[0] ^ 0x34)
new_packet.append(new_bytes[1] ^ 0x12)    

# Similarly for the 4-byte value
new_bytes = struct.unpack('BBBB', packet_data[i:i+4])
new_packet.append(new_bytes[0] ^ 0x78)
new_packet.append(new_bytes[1] ^ 0x56)
new_packet.append(new_bytes[2] ^ 0x34)
new_packet.append(new_bytes[3] ^ 0x12)
```

Comment: the problem seems to be inside the while loop. Thanks for pointing that out though.

Comment: Right, I pointed out the error with the 2-byte line, but the same problem exists in the 4-byte line: you would need 4 separate appends, one for each byte.

Comment: aah, let me try that.

Comment: got rid of the error but not getting the right result. hmmm.

Comment: Make sure you are XORing the right bytes with the right values, considering endianness.

Comment: See my edit; I had the bytes mixed up, so I picked the wrong part of  the constant to XOR with each byte of the result of `struct.unpack`.

Comment: Yup, that seemed to make sense and did work. Thank you, cheers :)